# Unable to select / copy a table – VBA Selenium ChromeDriver

Tags: excel, vba, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver, webdriver

I’m using Selenium / VBA / ChromeDriver to navigate a proprietary cloud system. On some pages I can find the text I need for FindElementByID or FindElementByPartialLinkText using INSPECT. However, on most pages the text seems scrubbed out. I have not been able to get FindElementByTagName or FindElementByClass to help. Because each Tag and Class is used many times, I can’t locate the right one. I have also not found a way to use FindElementByXPath.

This reduces me to navigate via SendKeys (“{TAB}{TAB}{TAB}{ENTER}”) and similar, with TIMER loops. This sort of works, although it’s fragile. Where I’ve been stuck is getting a resulting table of data into Excel.

When I navigate the page interactively I can select all, copy, and paste into Excel using (“^A”) then (“^C”). Selenium is not processing these SendKeys to copy the table. I have seen suggestions to SwitchToFrame, but INSPECT doesn’t display any frame elements. Even if I saw frame elements, since I’m not seeing any display names, I don't think FindElementByXPath would work so I could SwitchToFrame.

Any suggestions?

*** ADDED CODE WITH COMMENTS ***

The example finds customers with a given date of birth (DOB) and wants to paste into Excel. This VBA code displays the right table (I can also pop a modal) but I can't find a way to grab the data. Interactively, it works when I ^A and ^C, but these keys don't seem to work in Selenium.

```
Sub BotProcedure()

'   Initialize then launch website – section works well
Dim bot As New WebDriver
Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("TestTab")
bot.Start "Chrome", ""
bot.Get https://www.website.com/default.aspx

'   Log in to website – section works well
Call WasteTime(3)
bot.FindElementById("txtLoginID").SendKeys ("USERID")
bot.FindElementById("txtLoginPW").SendKeys ("PASSWORD")
bot.FindElementById("login-btn").Click
Call WasteTime(2)

'   Use SendKeys to navigate the menu and select the search page – section works well
bot.FindElementById("txtSearchMenu").SendKeys ("Customer Search")
bot.FindElementById("txtSearchMenu").Click
Call WasteTime(2)                                                        ' Allow time for search results
SendKeys ("{TAB}{TAB}{ENTER}")                              ' TAB to Customer Search selection and click it
Call WasteTime(2)                                                       ' Allow time for patient page to pop
SendKeys ("{TAB}{TAB}{TAB}{TAB}{TAB}{TAB}")     ' 6 TAB to Name field
SendKeys ("SMITH{ENTER}")                                     ' Enter Name
SendKeys ("{TAB}{TAB}{TAB}{TAB}{TAB}{TAB}")     ' 6 TAB to SEARCH button
SendKeys ("{ENTER}")                                                  ' Enter customer Search
Call WasteTime(1)                                                        ' Let the search happen

'   Code that didn’t find the Name field on the customer search page
'bot.FindElementByPartialLinkText("Name").Click
'bot.FindElementByTagName("tbody").Click
'bot.findElementByTagName ("body")
'bot.FindElementByClass("grid-content").Click

'    Use SendKeys to select ALL then COPY – doesn’t work.
'    This also doesn't select when data is in a modal
SendKeys ("^A")       ' Try to Select All in the modal
Call WasteTime(1)     ' Observation time - is the data selected?
SendKeys ("^C")       ' Copy the data to the clipboard
Call WasteTime(1)     ' Observation time - is the data copied?

'    Move to the destination workbook – this works
ws.Activate          ' Activate the Excel output location
Range("A1").Select   ' Select the Destination for data
Call WasteTime(1)    ' Observe if navigation worked

'    Paste to the workbook – but nothing is on the clipboard
SendKeys ("+{F10}S{DOWN}{DOWN}{ENTER}")     ' but clipboard is empty

'Body = bot.FindElementByClass("objbox").Attribute("innerHTML")
'ws.Range("A1").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues

' CODE BITS THAT DON’T WORK
' bot.FindElementByClass("date-picker").SendKeys ("01011980")
' bot.FindElementById("dtpDOB_txtCalendar").SendKeys ("01011980")
' bot.FindElementByPartialLinkText("Search").Click
' bot.FindElementById("btnPrint").Click
' bot.FindElementByPartialLinkText("Print").Click
'Set clipboard = GetObject("New:{1C3B4210-F441-11CE-B9EA-00AA006B1A69}")
'    With clipboard
'        .GetFromClipboard
'        Data = .GetText
'    End With

'  HERE I TRIED COPYING TEXT FROM EACH HTML CELL
'Set TableDiv = bot.getElementsByClassName("objbox").Item(0)
'Set TableDiv = bot.getElementsByTagName("tbody").Item(0)
'For Each Tr In TableDiv.getElementsByTagName("tr")
'    tdlen = Tr.getElementsByTagName("td").Length
'    If tdlen > 1 Then
'        lr = Sheet2.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row + 1
' ws.Range("C" & i).Value = Tr.getElementsByTagName("td").Item(0).innerText
' ws.Range("D" & i).Value = Tr.getElementsByTagName("td").Item(1).innerText
' ws.Range("E" & i).Value = Tr.getElementsByTagName("td").Item(2).innerText
'    End If
'Next Tr

End Sub

Sub WasteTime(HoldSecs)
        DelayTime = Timer + HoldSecs
        Do
            DoEvents
        Loop While Timer < DelayTime
End Sub
```

Comment: Welcome Brett! Please take some time to read the introduction to Stack Overflow and earn your first badge. We're a little bit different from other sites. Here's how...  https://stackoverflow.com/tour

Comment: What have you tried? Show some code.

Comment: *However, on most pages the text seems scrubbed out. I have not been able to get FindElementByTagName or FindElementByClass to help. Because each Tag and Class is used many times, I can’t locate the right one. I have also not found a way to use FindElementByXPath.* What does this mean? Give an example of some code.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.